# Finding the type of query executed in perl DBI

Tags: perl, dbi

In my perl program I have a function which takes a query as input and executes it and prints any rows fetched if the query is a select statement.

But the problem is with update or insert statements where fetchrow_array gives an error so is there any way i can know what type of query was executed so that i can skip the fetch part?

Comment: your program is full of errors

Comment: good luck with that ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not knowing what sort of SQL you are executing sounds like a bad idea to me, but that's not what you asked, so...

Check [the docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#execute) and you will find:

> You can tell if the statement was a SELECT statement by checking if
>   $sth->{NUM_OF_FIELDS} is greater than zero after calling execute.

Comment: Will try that. Is it that bad an issue?? its some convenience code i wrote for myself.

Answer (score 0):

Create a little helper function using a regular expressions to check the SQL string for specific words in the query...

```
my $sql = "UPDATE some_table SET some_value = 'abc' WHERE some_value = 'xyz'";

sub get_query_type
{
    my $sql_string = shift;
    my $query_type;

    if( $sql_string =~ m/^UPDATE/i )
    {
        $query_type = "An UPDATE query";
        # do UPDATE stuff
    }
    elsif( $sql_string =~ m/^INSERT/i )
    {
        $query_type = "An INSERT query";
        # do INSERT stuff
    }
    # more blocks here as needed.

    return $query_type;
}

my $type = get_query_type( $sql );

print $type;
```